# Зачем нам [программы]?

Tags: предложение, метки, синонимы-меток, удаление-метки

Объединить и удалить:

[программа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b0)
[программы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d1%8b)

Краткое описание у метки гласит

> НЕ ИСПОЛЬЗУЙТЕ ЭТУ МЕТКУ. Здесь практически все вопросы — о программах. Лучше добавьте метку конкретного языка или фреймворка

Не стоит ли их наконец-то удалить?

Comment: И на что заменить в тех вопросах где стоит только эта метка?

Comment: а взять и удалить не проще чем вопрос на мете напистаь?)

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму почему-то же их раньше не удалили, а только метку поставили. Лучше уточнить.

Comment: Ну было же тут уже такое обсуждение...

Comment: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/4338/178988

Comment: @Qwertiy, так оно же ни к чему не привело

Comment: метка [microsoft] тоже имеет такое описание, нашел на этом вопросе: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/980752/319552

Comment: @trollingchar имхо она так же обща и бесполезна. Для конкретных продуктов Микрософта есть свои метки. Поднимете вопрос об удалении здесь на Мете?

Comment: @Kromster это и хотел сделать, просто проверял вопрос на дубликатность